# Does Cider have live templates like Cursive(IntelliJ IDEA) does?

Tags: emacs, clojure, lisp, clojurescript, cider

I'm new to emacs/cider for Clojure development. I could not find a way to create [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/live-templates.html) in Cider like I do in IntelliJ IDEA (Cursive plugin).

Comment: If i understand you correctly, in emacs it is called `yasnippet`: https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet , like this for example: https://github.com/swannodette/clojure-snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yasnippet is a general method in emacs for modes to provide "templating". Not that many people that I know using clojure all day use it directly, of the folks i know most of them use it through the `clj-refactor` emacs package

https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clj-refactor.el

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use snippets, then please use https://github.com/mpenet/clojure-snippets

The package by David Nolen is no longer maintained: https://github.com/swannodette/clojure-snippets#warning

Also, note that the snippets used in yasnippet for clojure, are out of date. There was an attempt at updating them, see here: https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/issues/162

So to be safe, just go with https://github.com/mpenet/clojure-snippets